# Identical AUC for each fold in cross-validation ROC curves [Python]

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression, cross-validation, roc

**UPDATE**
I randomly & independently shuffled the data as @Paul suggest and my classifier has random performance now .

[image]
[image]

I have an **imbalanced** dataset with around 200.000 instances and 50 predictors. **The imbalance has a 4:1 ratio for the negative class (i.e class 0)**. In other words the negative class makes around 80% of the samples and the positive just 20% of the samples.

It's a **binary classification problem** where I have a target vector with 0's and 1's.

I have been trying to fit several classifiers like logistic regression and random forest.

I evaluate them with cross -validation  `skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=999)`and ROC `roc_curve` from Python `sklearn v.018`

**My Problem**

My ROC curve for each validation fold are almost the same and I have no idea why. The `AUC` is identical and always absurdly good (`0.9`). Although the Precision-Recall Curve shows worse `AUC=0.74` (which I think it's more accurate).

I tried following this example for ROC with cross-validation: http://lijiancheng0614.github.io/scikit-learn/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc_crossval.html#example-model-selection-plot-roc-crossval-py

**ROC curves Logistic Regression**

[image]

**ROC curves Confidence Interval Logistic Regression [zoomed in]**

[image]
**Precision Recall curves**
[image: PR curve]

**The question**:
Why does the performance of the model seem to be similar on each fold? shouldn't the AUC differ at least slightly?

**Code Below**

```
X, y = shuffle(X, y, random_state=0)
clasifier = linear_model.LogisticRegression(class_weight = "balanced")
clasifier.fit(X,y)
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
    mean_tpr = 0.0
    mean_fpr = linspace(0, 1, 100)

    skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=n_folds, shuffle=True, random_state=999)

    for i, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(skf.split(X,y)):
        # calculate the probability of each class assuming it to be positive
        probas_ = classifier.fit(X[train_index], y[train_index]).predict_proba(X[test_index])
        # Compute ROC curve and area under the curve
        fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y[test_index], probas_[:, 1], pos_label=1)
        mean_tpr += interp(mean_fpr, fpr, tpr)
        mean_tpr[0] = 0.0
        roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)

        plt.plot(fpr, tpr, lw=1, label='ROC fold %d (area = %0.2f)' % (i+1, roc_auc))

    plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], '--', color=(0.6, 0.6, 0.6), label='Random', lw=2)


    mean_tpr /= n_folds
    mean_tpr[-1] = 1.0
    mean_auc = auc(mean_fpr, mean_tpr)

    plt.plot(mean_fpr, mean_tpr, 'k--',
         label='Mean ROC (area = %0.2f)' % mean_auc, lw=3)
    plt.xlim([-0.05, 1.05])
    plt.ylim([-0.05, 1.05])
    plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate (1- specificity)', fontsize=18)
    plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate (sensitivity)', fontsize=18)
```

Comment: At a glance, I don't see anything wrong. Could you randomise your class labels before training to check that your prediction can fail if there is nothing to predict? Also, your intuition is right that the mean precision is the more sensitive measure for an imbalanced data set.

Comment: @Paul I didn't add that, but I am randomising my data before fitting like this : `X, y = shuffle(X, y, random_state=0)`. Should I randomize it before every fitting? I didn't get you exactly

Comment: I presume that this shuffle function randomises X and y concurrently. I think it would be good test what your chance performance is, i.e. what performance you achieve when you shuffle X and y independently from another.

Comment: @Paul yes, indeed. how can I shuffle them independently? wouldn't the association between observations and their labels will be lost? after googling, I only found `sklearn.utils.shuffle` in python. are you aware of another function? thanks.

Comment: Loosing the association between the observations and the labels is the point in this case. When your code exceeds your expectations, you want to make sure that it can also fail. ;-) For the shuffling, you could just use `numpy.random.shuffle`, assuming that your first dimension indexes samples. It shuffles the array in place, so make a copy a copy first: `Xrand = X.copy(); numpy.random.shuffle(Xrand); yrand = y.copy(); numpy.random.shuffle(y)`.

Comment: Seems like your classifier is just that good then. Congratulations.

Comment: Thank you, Paul! still doesn't my ROC suggest slight overfitting? or is it bad to use for imbalanced data?

Comment: By using separate training and test sets, you are doing the most important thing to control overfitting. On top of that, you are using cross-validation, and I assume that you then average your model coefficients across the different folds? Of course, you could add some sort of regularizer to your model, but at some point you will hit diminishing returns. IMO, you have already implemented the two steps that will probably give you the most mileage.